# Tweet counter only shows more than 0 on root page?

Tags: php, html, twitter

I have the twitter button on the top of my page using the following code in my header file:

```
<script src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<a href="http://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-count="horizontal">Tweet</a>
```

However, the count only shows the number of tweets we have on the root page, i.e., www.website.com. www.website.com/anything does not show a tweet count other than 0.

Does anyone have any solutions for this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the goal to always show the number of tweets for the root page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To always use the root page, add the `data-url` attribute to the anchor tag.

```
<script src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<a href="http://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-count="horizontal" data-url="http://www.website.com">Tweet</a>
```

Check out the [Tweet button documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/tweet-button) for more options.